# Cap deploy asks for password even though ssh key is present in server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, setup-deployment

When I try to ssh to a server, I'm able to do it as my `id_rsa.pub` key is added to the authorized keys in the server.

Now when I try to deploy my code via Capistrano to the server from my local project folder, the server asks for a password.

I'm unable to understand what could be the issue if I'm able to ssh and unable to deploy to the same server.

$ cap deploy:setup

```
"no seed data"
triggering start callbacks for `deploy:setup'
* 13:42:18 == Currently executing `multistage:ensure'
*** Defaulting to `development'
* 13:42:18 == Currently executing `development'
* 13:42:18 == Currently executing `deploy:setup'
triggering before callbacks for `deploy:setup'
* 13:42:18 == Currently executing `db:configure_mongoid'
* executing "mkdir -p /home/deploy/apps/development/flyingbird/shared/config"
 servers: ["dev1.noob.com", "176.9.24.217"]
 Password:
```

Comment: Have you tried running `ssh-add path/to/key` before deploying?

Comment: It still asks for password for creating folders on server

Comment: You say the password is present on the server, but for which user?

`set :user, "user1"` is the user Capistrano tries to log in with, not the user you run Capistrano as.

Comment: It's present for the user i run capistrano as and both the users are diff.

Comment: It looks like it is asking for a password during 'db:configure_mongoid' step, is it possible this is not asking for ssh password but a db password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, there was staging.rb, development.rb files which were overriding my cap script credentials whenever tried to deploy the application in different env.

Comment: I'm too facing this problem really can't figure out, how did you solved.